# Style div like the submit button

Tags: html, css, submit

Is it possible in css to style a div that it looks like a submit button? Of course it's easy to do this for one browser using css, but I'm looking for a cross browser solution.

```
<div class="submit">Submit</div>
//should look the same like:
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

The reason is, that I have different kinds of buttons and I like to go xhtml strict where it is forbidden to use input fields outside a formular.

Comment: umh thanks, I totally forgot this element ;) http://nickcowie.com/presentation/s5-button.html

Comment: Why not have a form? That way the button can do something without being completely dependant on JavaScript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use `<button>` it will look different in each browser.

With jQuery it is very easy to make cross browser buttons:
http://jqueryui.com/button/

To submit a form just bind click event. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AELMs/

```
$(function() {
    $("a").button().click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().submit();
    });
});


<form action="#">
    <a href="#">An anchor</a>
</form>
```